# Problems while showing activity when app comes from background to foreground

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have created an android application. I am trying to call a `PinLoginActivity` every time when the user comes from background to foreground. I am using the below method to detect the `onStart` and `onStop` of all the activities in my application and its working perfectly fine.

```
class YourApplication : Application() {

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(AppLifecycleTracker())
  }

}

class AppLifecycleTracker : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks  {
  private var numStarted = 0

  override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity?) {
    if (numStarted == 0) {      
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PinLoginActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("LockScreen", true);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
    numStarted++
  }

  override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity?) {
    numStarted--
    if (numStarted == 0) {        
    }
  }   
}
```

**Now the problem is:**

I am accessing gallery from within my app. Once I open the gallery, select image and comes back to my app. I am getting the `PinLoginActivity`. How can I avoid calling the `PinLoginActivity` to be called in this scenario ?

Comment: either don't use `startActivityForResult` as this takes you out of your app into another app which is "insecure" therefore should require a pin (and implement your own image picker). Or increment your counter before you start the gallery activity and decrement it in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: or you can just call a method in Application and set a flag to true for gallery and then check if the flag is set the true and act accordingly

Comment: How can I do that? @vikaskumar

Comment: @Blundell I have this callbacks in Application.java file. How to increment counter in the Activity in which I am calling gallery ?

Comment: is there any way to know the previous activity from which the current foreground activity was called ? @Blundell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample is how you can set a flag in Application and check if the gallery is about to open

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
static boolean isGallery;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public static void setGalleryFlag(boolean isTrue){
    isGallery = isTrue;
}

public void checkGallery(){
    if (isGallery){
        //hide your activity
    }else{
        //operate normally
    }
}
```

}

so when you about to open the gallery just set the flag to true

```
private void startGallery() {
    Application.setGalleryFlag(true);
    //open the gallery now
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Let me try it in all scenarios and will update you. One more thing. is there any way to know the previous activity from which the current foreground activity was called ?

Comment: Only if you pass that knowledge in the Intent bundle (and therefore anyone who isn't you that starts an activity - won't have that in the bundle)